# jQuery validate require two field or one other filed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been looking but have not found a solution for my specific need. I have a total of 3 fields (first_name, last_name, and business_name). I want users to either enter both first and last name or just the business name.

I've several methods, here's my most recent attempt.

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
<input type="text" id="first_last" name="first_last">
<input type="text" id="bus_name" name="bus_name">

rules : {
    first_name1 : {
        required: function(element){
           return $("#bus_name").val().length = 0;
        }
    },
    last_name1 : {
        required : function(element){
           return $("#bus_name").val().length = 0;
        }
    },
    bus_name1: {
        required : function(element){
          return ($("#first_name").is(':empty') && $("#last_name").is(':empty') ? true : false);
    }
}
```

I've also tried creating a custom method. Needless to say it didn't work.

```
$.validator.addMethod("busnameRequired", function(value, element) {
var firstname1 = $("#first_name").val().length,
        lastname1 = $("#last_name").val().length;

if(firstname + lastname == 0) {
  return true;
}else{
    return false;
} 
}, "Enter Business Name");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't edit the coding mistakes out of your question, thereby possibly disconnecting any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conditional Rules:**

You have all kinds of little issues on the first attempt...

1. You declared a rule on `first_name1` but this field is named `first_name`.   The plugin needs the correct `name` attribute.
2. You declared a rule on `last_name1` but this field is named `first_last`.  The plugin needs the correct `name` attribute.
3. You declared a rule on `bus_name1` but this field is named `bus_name`.  The plugin needs the correct `name` attribute.
4. You're checking length on some rules but checking `:empty` on the other.  Use `.is(':blank')` on all of them instead.

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/n8gvvb92/

---

**Custom Method:**

In your custom rule, your logic is backwards. You're presently returning `true` when the name fields are empty. You will want to return `false` in that case so that you trigger the validation error message.

You'll also want to use `.is(':blank')` here too.

Something like this is closer to what you want, but will still need some work.

```
$.validator.addMethod("busnameRequired", function (value, element) {
    return ($("#first_name").is(':blank') && $("#last_name").is(':blank')) ? false : true;
}, "Enter Business Name");
```

Comment: thank you for your response! You're right for simplicity I removed the "1" from my form fields. I looked at both DEMO you've provided but it's not working the way I want. My apologies for not explaining more clearly.

Comment: @user752746, the two demos are working *exactly* the way you've described.  It was not simply a matter of removing the `1`.  `first_last` is still not the same as `last_name`.

Comment: I want the users to either enter both (first and last name) or just enter the (business name). The second allows business name to be blank with first and last name are populated. But it does work with business name populated and first and last name is blank.

Comment: @user752746, then simply write another custom rule for the first & last name fields... it's going to be almost identical to the custom rule for the business field.  Thanks to my answer, you now know exactly how to implement this.

Comment: Thank you the first DEMO is working exactly the way I want. thank you very much!

Comment: @user752746, You're welcome.  I also since removed my second demo from the answer.